# Exponential of Jordan matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, jordan-normal-form, matrix-exponential

If J is a Jordan matrix. How to prove that the elements on the principle diagonal of $ e^J$ are exponential function of elements on the principle diagonal of $J$?

If it is two dimensional, then I can prove by calculating it. I have trouble proving it in general n $\times$ n case. Could anyone kindly help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For square matrices, we can sometimes explicitly calculate the infinite sum if there is a clear pattern to
$$ e^A = I + A + \frac{1}{2} A^2 +  \frac{1}{6} A^3 + \frac{1}{24} A^4 + \cdots  $$

A Jordan block is a square (sub)matrix with all the same element $\lambda$ on the main diagonal and then all 1's on the immediate upper off-diagonal. That is, we can write $$ J = \lambda  I + N,   $$ where $N$ is all zeroes except for the immediate off-diagonal. Since $I$ and $N$ commute, so do $\lambda I$ and $N$ commute.

The main analysis theorem is that, whenever square matrices $A,B$ commute, then
$$ e^{A+B} = e^A e^B = e^B e^A. $$ You should familiarize yourself with this theorem; for one thing, find a proof in your book.

Apply to $A = \lambda I $ and $B = N.$ What is $e^N?$  Please do the 2 by 2 and 3 by 3 cases by hand, actually 4 by 4 as well:

$$
N = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Finally, what is $e^{\lambda I}?$